# Как написать свой планировщик задач?

Tags: php

У меня есть скрипт, мне нужно чтоб он срабатывал два раза в день. Как на php написать, чтоб этот скрипт так работал?

Comment: а что cron умер?

Comment: для этого есть cron

Comment: Евгений четко написал что хочет написать СВОЙ планировщик задач :)

Comment: @madfan41k Вот Вот)))) А они мне тут cron, да cron советуют)) Можно же написать, чтоб скрипт срабатывал два раза в день? И если можно, то как?)

Comment: Да хоть через sleep ))). Или через расчет времени функцией time. Или писать своего демона. Но зачем танцы с бубном, когда есть cron - специально для этого созданный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать [phpJobScheduler](http://www.phpjobscheduler.co.uk/) он работает через БД.

Также можете организовать это самостоятельно с помощью таблицы в БД в которой задавать время запуска скрипта.

Как более действенный вариант для замены - это разместить нужный скрипт в отдельном классе основанном на создании system daemon с помощью php.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.register-shutdown-function.php

register_shutdown_function — Регистрирует функцию, которая выполнится при завершении работы скрипта.

Регистрирует функцию callback, которая выполнится после завершения работы скрипта или при вызове функции exit().

register_shutdown_function(['Cron', 'run'));

Данный пример вызовет статический метод run класса Cron.

После завершения скрипта - реализовать выполнение cron задач.

Comment: Добавил описание (=